# Bluetooth status on statusbar

Tags: android, bluetooth, imageview, status, statusbar

I have  my own application home screen as default home screen for  my android device. I have a status bar in my application and I am managing the Bluetooth connection status with an Imageview(onclick) in that status bar.

If I click on the Imageview in my statusbar I am turning the bluetooth on/off. I am changing the background of imageview according to the status of bluetooth.

If bluetooth is ON -  Blueimage

If bluetooth is OFF - greyImage

So my question is - If I enable/disable the bluetooth in bluetoth settings page and press the back button and navigate to my home screen then Imageview(background image) in my status bar should get changed automatically.

I tried a lot updating the image of  imageview  on back button press(by overriding onbackpressed method) but no result.

Is there any similar API with which we can read/store the status of bluetooth in a variable as soon as we enable/disable the bluetooth in bluetooth settings page and according to that the status bar imageview backround will get changed automatically?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can put the code that checked for the Bluetooth status in the onRestart() method

like this:

```
public class yourClass {

 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

 // your code
 }

 public void onRestart() {

 // put the checked code for the Bluetooth status here  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried it but on back press the Imageview is not getting changed ( I tried enabling bluetooth in settings page and pressed back buton)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add broadcast receivers in your code to receive once bluetooth is switched on or off in your activity class. for your reference :

```
public void onCreate() {

    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter2);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter3);
```

}

//The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
        ... //Device found
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        ... //Device is now connected
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
         ... //Done searching
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED.equals(action)) {
        ... //Device is about to disconnect
        }
        else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
        ... //Device has disconnected
        }
```

once you receives the status do your functionality .. done !!

Comment: Thanks, but I want to update the Imageview on status bar on pressing the back button of my device once I enable/disable the bluettoth in bluetooth setings page.

Comment: why you want to do so ?? and remember while overriding onBackPressed() you must need to remove super.onBackPressed() else your activity will be destroyed !!

Comment: In my question I mentioned the same which I stated above, I have my own application set as default home screen for my device and now If I enable bluetooth In bluetooth settings page and on pressing back button the ImageView should be get changed In the status bar(I am using 2 .png files for Imageview background, one for ON and one for OFF)